# Testing comments controller. Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

I want to test comments controller, action create, but I don't know how do this.
**comments_controller**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @hotel = Hotel.find(params[:hotel_id])
    @comment = @hotel.comments.new(comment_params)
    @comment.user_id = current_user.id
    @comment.save
    redirect_to @hotel
end

private
  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:user_id, :body, :hotel_id)
  end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
  resources :hotels do
    resources :comments
    get 'list', on: :collection
    post 'comment'
  end
```

**comments_controller_spec.rb**

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe CommentsController do
  login_user
  describe 'POST create' do

    it 'create a new comment with valid attributes' do
      expect{
        comment_attr = attributes_for(:comment)
        post :create, comment: comment_attr
      }.to change(Comment,:count).by(1)
    end

    it 'redirects to the new comment' do
      comment_attr = attributes_for(:comment)
      post :create, comment: comment_attr
      expect(response).to redirect_to hotels_path(hotel)
    end

  end

end
```

**factories.rb**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do |user|
    user.email { Faker::Internet.email }
    user.password 'password'
    user.password_confirmation 'password'
  end

  factory :hotel do |hotel|
    hotel.title 'Hotel'
    hotel.description 'This is a some description for hotel'
    hotel.breakfast true
    hotel.price 20500
    hotel.address { create(:address) }
    hotel.user { create(:user) }
    hotel.avatar { fixture_file_upload(Rails.root + 'spec/fixtures/images/example.jpg', "image/jpg") }
  end

  factory :comment do |comment|
    comment.body 'This is a some comment ^_^'
    comment.user { create(:user) }
    comment.hotel { create(:hotel) }
  end

  factory :address do |address|
    address.country { Faker::Address.country }
    address.state { Faker::Address.state }
    address.city { Faker::Address.city }
    address.street { Faker::Address.street_name }
  end
end
```

But I have this error:

> 1) CommentsController POST create create a new comment with valid
>   attributes
>        Failure/Error: post :create, comment: comment_attr
>        ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
>          No route matches {:comment=>{:body=>"This is a some comment ^_^", :user=>"5", :hotel=>"1"}, :controller=>"comments",
>   :action=>"create"}
>        # ./spec/controllers/comments_controller_spec.rb:10:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
>        # ./spec/controllers/comments_controller_spec.rb:8:in`block (3 levels) in '
>
> 2) CommentsController POST create redirects to the new comment
>        Failure/Error: post :create, comment: comment_attr
>        ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
>          No route matches {:comment=>{:body=>"This is a some comment ^_^", :user=>"5", :hotel=>"1"}, :controller=>"comments",
>   :action=>"create"}
>        # ./spec/controllers/comments_controller_spec.rb:16:in `block (3 levels) in '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your main problem is that you send to action already created object

```
post :create, comment: Comment.create(comment_attr)
```

Rails parses params and fetches `id` of record and trying to find `member` route.
It looks like you would like to test that a new Comment will be created from params in controller. And it is nested resource so you should send `hotel_id` as well
Try to send

```
it 'creates a new comment with valid attributes' do
  comment_attr = attributes_for(:comment)
  hotel = Hotel.last || create(:hotel)

  expect{
    post :create, comment: comment_attr, hotel_id: hotel.id
  }.to change(Comment,:count).by(1)
end
```

Another thing which confuses me is line `post 'comment', only: :create` in routes. I have never seen option `only` for `post` - usually it is used for resources.

Comment: Thanks, I did this `post create, comment: comment_attr` but this don't solve my problem.

Comment: is error the same? have you tried to change routes (I mean remove option `only` for post)?

Comment: see update in the answer. You should send `hotel_id` because your resource is nested